# Windows single sign-on from a java client

Tags: java, windows, iis, single-sign-on

I'm trying to find a solution for a java client to use the logged in windows authentication while connecting to a web application fronted by an IIS server. To be more explicit, this is the use case:

1. Domain user A logs in to their Windows account
2. A starts client application C which connects to the IIS with which it authenticates using the already confirmed Windows identity (without asking for a user/password)
3. IIS forwards the authenticated user to a Tomcat application it communicates with through AJP (but this is outside the scope of this question)

It's step 2 that I'm having problems implementing. We had this working through the experimental apache httpclient native NTLM authenticator which recently stopped working for reasons I can't figure out yet (a JNI native function api call fails). After trying for a while to fix it, I'm now attempting to come up with a new way of doing this because

1. NTLM is sidelined by Microsoft themselves
2. The apache httpclient native NTLM authenticator also seems to be no longer developed

IIS reverse-proxying is a requirement, I can't go directly to Tomcat.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to add your site's domain to Trusted sites in the `Internet Options` on the client computer. On the other hand, you can try Kerberos authentication, just refer to this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49159075/windows-integrated-authentication-for-java-web-application-sso